# Replace welcome screen (aka "splash" screen) with calendar?

Tags: start-up, calendar

I want to replace the welcome screen with the calendar.

I've tried adding `(calendar)` to my `.emacs` but it opens calendar in addition to the welcome screen not instead of it.

---

EDIT: I'm trying what is suggested by @Drew, I press `M-x customize-option` and then enter `initial-buffer-choice`. Which brings me here.

[image]

Would I enter the Calendar command on this page, or did something go wrong?

Comment: Choose `Value Menu` to see the possibilities. Refer to my answer for more info, including this: *ensure that when you start up Emacs the necessary **function has been defined** or the named **buffer has been created***. And read the relevant manual section. IOW, find out about this and understand it before you try to use Customize to set the value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can customize option `initial-buffer-choice` (using `M-x customize-option`).

The value can be a buffer name (the name of your calendar buffer, if it exists - e.g. `"*Calendar*"`) or a function that returns a buffer. The buffer is displayed in place of the welcome (aka "splash") screen.

It is of course up to you to ensure that when you start up Emacs the necessary function has been defined or the named buffer has been created.

See the Emacs manual, node [Entering Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Entering-Emacs.html).

Comment: I updated my question with what happened when I try this.

Answer (score 2):

I hope so ...

- You should append into `~/.emacs` file, as a first line, next command:`(setq inhibit-splash-screen t) ;; it'll disable splash screen`
- At the end of `~/.emacs` join the next sequence:

  ```
  (let ((buffer-cal "\*Calendar\*"))
    ;;
    ;; next commands:
    ;;
    ;; create calendar and pass focus to it
    ;;
    (and
     (calendar) (bufferp (get-buffer buffer-cal))
     (switch-to-buffer buffer-cal)
     )
    (delete-other-windows)
  )
  ```

Comment: thanks, I copy and pasted into my `.emacs` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use org-agenda you can try the extension Emacs Dashboard.
https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard

Comment: Please consider elaborating - describe what the solution provided by that link does - how it solves the problem. So far, this is a link-only answer, which thus risks being deleted.